# Conflict between polyglossia and glossaries-extra?

Tags: polyglossia, glossaries-extra, bib2gls

I’m trying to get to the bottom of an odd issue I’m having when using the `glossaries-extra` package, specifically its `record` option which is necessary in order for it to work with the bib2gls tool.

Whenever I use this option in conjunction with `polyglossia`, it throws the following error:

```
! Undefined control sequence
<argument> \TrackLangRequireDialectPrefix
                                          \CurrentTrackedTag .ldf
l. 11249 {}
```

The problem cannot lie with the contents of the glossary because the error even occurs when no glossary is loaded at all.

An MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english} 
% if I delete the \setdefaultlanguage line the error 
% disappears, but using polyglossia without defining a 
% language is kind of pointless. Also other packages such 
% as biblatex really don’t like it

\usepackage[record]{glossaries-extra}

\begin{document}

Random text to prevent an empty output

\end{document}
```

The document does compile alright, but the error, aside from being seriously annoying, does not seem like something I should just ignore.

After a bit of digging I suspect that the issue somehow lies with the `tracklang` package (loaded by `glossaries-extra`) trying to find a language definition file and apparently failing to assign `\CurrentTrackedTag` (which seems to be a local variable) correctly in the process. So I initially wondered whether I made a mistake in defining my default language, but I followed the `polyglossia` manual to the letter. In fact it doesn’t seem to matter what language I fill in (as well as whether or not and which additional options I use), or even if I use `babel` instead of polyglossia, the error is thrown regardless.

Any ideas on how to solve the issue?

(P.S.: I’m using XeLaTeX because I need CJK support.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! At the moment I can't quite reproduce the error message, but I'm not sure if I forgot to run an additional command. Can you double check that the example reproduces the error in an empty directory and describe which commands you run on it?

Comment: Anyway it is a known issue with `polyglossia` that it does not properly expose its language variants to other packages in a meaningful way (I assume many packages would like `babel` identifiers, but at the moment there is no unified interface on the `polyglossia` side for any variant detection). It could be that `tracklang` can not pick up the variant in certain situations and fails to guard against that. If you only write in English (and other Western/European languages), I would use `babel` instead of `polyglossia` (you mention the error pops up even then - did you delete the aux files?).

Comment: Can you add `\listfiles` to your MWE and show the result. (It should create a summary of all the packages with their versions at the end of the transcript.) I don't get an error so I suspect you may have an old version of `tracklang` .

Comment: @moewe: Yes, clearing the directory of all other files still produces the error, even if I just run `xelatex` on it. Same issue if I use babel (also in an otherwise empty directory).

@NicolaTalbot My version of `tracklang` is 1.3.5 (dated 2018/02/21).

Comment: @Abun The latest version of `tracklang` is 1.3.6 2018-05-13. What about the `glossaries-extra` version? The latest version of that is 1.36 2018-08-18. Both may need updating.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot I see, in that case I’ll probably have to uninstall TexLive and reinstall it vanilla (I’m currently using the one provided in the Ubuntu repositories which seems to still use the 2017 version of TexLive). I’ll check again once I’m done reinstalling.

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Updating solved the issue (for both `polyglossia` and `babel`. Awesome, thank you very much!